# How to save struct column as string to CSV/TSV in PySpark?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I've seen similar questions asked many times, but there's no clear answer to something that should be easy.

How can a struct column be saved to CSV (tsv actually) in PySpark? I want to serialize it and save as JSON.

I have a dataframe, which I read from parquet, that contains the following schema:

```
timestamp:long
timezoneOffset:string
dayInterval:integer
speed:double
heading:double
ignitionStatus:integer
segmentId:string
pointMM:struct
    mmResult:array
        element:struct
            primitiveId:long
            rnId:integer
            internalId:integer
            isFromTo:boolean
            offset:double
            probability:double
            distanceToArc:double
            headingDifference:double
    isSuccessful:boolean
```

The `pointMM` column is a struct, that contains an array of structs, and another bool field (`isSuccessful`). I'm able to read this data from parquet and preview it:
[image]

If I want to save this data to CSV/TSV I get the following error:

```
df.write.csv(output_path, sep='\t')

AnalysisException: CSV data source does not support struct<mmResult:array<struct<primitiveId:bigint,rnId:int,internalId:int,isFromTo:boolean,offset:double,probability:double,distanceToArc:double,headingDifference:double>>,isSuccessful:boolean> data type.
```

Is there a way, even better an **easy** to convert the pointMM column to JSON string and save it to TSV?

Is there a way to do it with explicitly stating the schema of `pointMM`? Or a way to do it, even better, without knowing the schema?

I don't understand why this is difficult, because as you can see in the attached screenshot, that column is shown in JSON format.

EDIT 1: I understand that `display()` function somehow serializes the columns struct. Is there a way to use the same serialization without reinventing the wheel?

EDIT 2: `.printSchema()` shows the schema of the DataFrame. Can this be somehow used to help serialize `pointMM` column to JSON?

[image: printing schema]

[image: print schema output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [df.dtypes](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.dtypes.html) to get the type of each column. If type is a `struct` use [to_json](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.to_json.html) on this column to convert the data into a json string. Otherwise select the column as it is:

```python
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

cols = [ F.to_json(c[0]).alias(c[0]) if c[1].startswith("struct") else F.col(c[0]) for c in df.dtypes]

df.select(cols).show(truncate=False)
```

Output:

```
+-----------+-------+--------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+-----+---------+--------------+
|dayInterval|heading|ignitionStatus|pointMM                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   |segmentId|speed|timestamp|timezoneOffset|
+-----------+-------+--------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+-----+---------+--------------+
|1          |271.1  |4             |{"isSuccessful":true,"mmResult":[{"distanceToArc":12.211,"headingDifference":12.1,"internalId":5,"isFromTo":true,"offset":12.1,"primitiveId":12,"probability":0.12,"rnId":4},{"distanceToArc":12.211,"headingDifference":12.1,"internalId":5,"isFromTo":true,"offset":12.1,"primitiveId":13,"probability":0.12,"rnId":4}]}|abc      |12.4 |12345678 |+1            |
+-----------+-------+--------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+-----+---------+--------------+
```

Comment: This is great! As I know which column is struct, it simplifies to `df=df.withColumn('pointMM', F.to_json('pointMM'))`